# Ruby on Rails | conditions in table alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I'm new in Ruby and Rails and I need your help to find the right way to do this.

I have the following database schema:

`employees` table have columns: *id*, *name* 
`company_infos` table have columns: *id*, _employee_id_, _chief_id_

CompanyInfo model has the followings associations,

```
class CompanyInfo < ApplicationRecord    
  belongs_to :employee    
  belongs_to :chief, class_name: 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'chief_id'
end
```

What I want to do is to filter the results with a keyword used for search the employee's or the chief's name.

I'm doing this but I'm getting the error

> Mysql unknown column chief.name

```
CompanyInfo.eager_load(:employee, :chief)
  .where("employees.name like '%something%'")
  .where("chief.name like '%something%'")
```

I would appreciate all the help you can give me. Thanks

Comment: Should not it be chefs instead of chef

Answer (score 0):

Only one `where` query will work in both case as both associations have same table

1. If you want to filter CompanyInfo which have employee of chief having name as 'something'

   ```
   CompanyInfo.includes(:employee, :chief).where("employees.name like '%something%'")
   ```
2. If you want query where you want to filter out CompanyInfo where 'something' is name for both employee and chief, try

   ```
   CompanyInfo.includes(:employee).where("employees.name like '%something%'")
     .includes(:chief).where("employees.name like '%something%'")
   ```